# In Pytest, how can I view the names of my tests as they are running?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I started out using the test framework that comes with Python3. Later I changed  to Pytest.

I expected that

```
Pytest my_file.py
```

would output the name of the currently running test, like the test framework that comes with python3 does, but it doesn't.

Is there an option that enables this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the `-v` option, a.k.a. `--verbose`:

```
pytest -v your_file.py
```

And you can get a list of all possible options:

```
pytest --help
```

Also, ideally, your project would be structured in such a way that you don't need to call pytest with an explicit script file as argument. I. e. test suites would be in separate script files with names of `test_XYZ.py`, living either in the project's main directory or in a subdirectory called `tests`, [as recommended by Kenneth Reitz](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/structure/). So you would just have to do:

```
pytest -v
```